# Why cd does not change current directory in crontab?

Tags: centos, cron, shell

In my user's crontab, on a CentOS system, I have something like this:

```
58 12 * * * cd /home/joe/dev; echo `pwd` | logger
```

This outputs in /var/log/messages:

```
Feb 19 12:58:01 srv01 joe: /home/joe
```

Instead of outputting:

```
Feb 19 12:58:01 srv01 joe: /home/joe/dev
```

Why is the directory not kept when outputting `pwd`?

Comment: This is partly correct.  Depending on the version of Cron.  Ubuntu flavor'd cron supports a user field preceding the command as you have in your first example.  I think it is an ubuntu-ism only, but it may be in other distro's as well.

Comment: possibly because the path `/home/joe/dev` doesn't exist - so the first command doesn't do anything.

Comment: What happens if you do `sh -c 'cd /home/joe/dev; echo \`pwd\` | logger'` instead?

Comment: @Daniel That's not for the user's crontab though, only the system-wide stuff.

Comment: @AD7six /home/joe/dev exists and permissions are ok.

Comment: @zoredache `sh -c 'cd /home/joe/dev; echo \`pwd\` | logger'` outputs /home/joe/dev

Comment: Guys, I feel bad, I managed to make it work however I don't know exactly how. But I think I might have made the mistake of not always exiting vim when I saved the changes to my crontab. I was used to edit the crontab manually and this time I was using `crontab -e`.

Comment: @Martinos that should be in the question (and emphasised) as it makes every answer except BeepBeep's "I tried that and it works fine" answer meaningless, since they are explaining a problem that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 7):

The following should work:

```
58 12 * * * (cd /home/joe/dev; echo `pwd` | logger)
```

By wrapping the commands in parentheses, you should force them all to run in the same subshell.

Comment: Parentheses are not needed. All commands are already running as in the same subshell.

Comment: As stated by the OP, [the question is a misunderstanding](https://serverfault.com/questions/669945/why-cd-does-not-change-current-directory-in-crontab#comment818999_669945) and the actual phenomenon doesn't exist.

Answer (score 6):

The commands are being run independently, so it is not the same as expecting them to run in the same shell/environment. You would probably be better served by creating a shell script that performs the desired commands and then calling the script from the crontab.

Update: The above was a guess, and/or proposed possibilty (as a comment so tersely and aggressively pointed out). So I decided to test on CentOS 6.6 and... I was wrong... The following crontab entry worked properly:

```
* * * * * echo \`pwd` |logger; cd /home; echo `pwd` |logger;
```

So that should have worked for you... I still maintain that you would be best serverd by calling scripts not individual commands in your crontab... but that is a preference (so please be kind in the comments...).

Comment: That sounds like a guess, to fit "observed" behavior.

Comment: Lots of 'answers' are guesses here.  That isn't necessarily a bad thing.  An educated guess can be very helpful in leading people to solving their problems.

Comment: @BeepBeep is right. If you use `;` in cron, there are two independent commands running. If you want to concatenate them, use `&&`.

Comment: The line that you wrote in you post works. However for some reason cd to my /home/joe/dev doesn't work. It seems to be a permission issue even the user running the cron is the same as the owner of the /home/joe/dev.

Comment: As the only sane answer (especially in light of [the question being a misunderstanding](http://serverfault.com/questions/669945/why-cd-does-not-change-current-directory-in-crontab?noredirect=1#comment818999_669945)) : +1. Please correct the escaped backtick, and preferably put the update first with emphasis - it doesn't matter to future readers you wrote something different originally.

Answer (score 3):

As per [this Unix&Linux SE answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38951/what-is-the-working-directory-when-cron-executes-a-job), you can replace `;` with `&&` as different versions of cron across different Linux distributions handle this type of functionality in different ways:

```
cd /home/joe/dev && echo `pwd` | logger
```

Comment: "need"? The linked answer says nothing about `;` not working. "My car doesn't start" "My blue car starts, you therefore need a blue car" is not a useful answer. (Note that the Asker comments that the question is effectively nonsense). -1.

Comment: @AD7six point taken, answer edited :)

Comment: Thanks for taking my comment constructively, DV removed. `different versions of cron across different Linux distributions...` - I don't know of _any_ version of cron, on any distro, that doesn't understand a semicolon, and of course `;` and `&&` are not logical equivalents.

Comment: As stated by the OP, [the question is a misunderstanding](https://serverfault.com/questions/669945/why-cd-does-not-change-current-directory-in-crontab#comment818999_669945), and the actual phenomenon doesn't exist